# Why UITableViewController with Generic data source does not call title for header?

Tags: swift, generics, tableview

I have superclass with generic data source 'items':
This class simply uses table view and show items.

```
class ViewController<T>: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var items: [T] = []
    var tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.setupTableView()
        self.placeTableView()
    }
    
    private func setupTableView() {
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func placeTableView() {
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: item)
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

Then I subclass it by new class 'MyViewController'.

```
class MyViewController: ViewController<String> {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.items = ["1", "2", "3"]
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Header"
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForFooterInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return "Footer"
    }
}
```

The question is why `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)` is not called ?

The data source is set.

But if I remove generic in superclass like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var items: [String] = []
    var tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = .white
        self.setupTableView()
        self.placeTableView()
    }
    
    private func setupTableView() {
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }

    func placeTableView() {
        self.view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: item)
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

It perfectly call `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int)` in 'MyViewController'.

Why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the hight for the table header ?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    10
}
```

Comment: Yes I have set it but It does not help me. And heightForHeaderInSection is used when we use viewForHeader, but I don't use it.

Comment: add the @override to the heightForHeaderInSection, when you use these delegate in your subclass

Comment: I cannot use @override for the heightForHeaderInSection because my superclass ('ViewController') does not implement heightForHeaderInSection. Even if I use heightForHeaderInSection in superclass and override it in child class it does not help. The section header has not appeared. I have check it right now.

Comment: The problem is when I use Generic. But I don't figure this out.